# descriptions of groups of order $45$

Tags: group-theory

Describe the structure of groups of order $45$
Let $|G|=45$

If $G$ has an element of order $45$
$G=＜x|x^{45}=1＞$

If $G$ doesn’t have an element of order $45$ 
$P_9$: $9$-Sylow group 
$P_5$: $5$-Sylow group 
$P_9 \triangleleft G$, $P_5 \triangleleft G$, $P_9 \cap P_5=\{1\}$ 
Hence $P_9×P_5$ (direct) 
$G=P_9×P_5$ (I’m not sure about this) 
$P_9=＜x,y| x^3=y^3=1, xy=yx＞$ 
$P_5=＜x| x^5=1＞$

This is what I’ve got.
I can’t describe the structure of $P_9×P_5$ 
I want to describe it like $G=＜...＞$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is fine. In a group of order $45$, the Sylow $3$-subgroup and the Sylow $5$-subgroup are necessarily normal. Hence the group is the direct product of these subgroups.

For a group of order $9$, you have two possibilities :

Either $C_9 = \langle x\mid x^9=1\rangle$ or $C_3\times C_3=\langle x,y\mid x^3=y^3=[x,y]=1\rangle$.

There is only one group of order $5$, namely $C_5=\langle x\mid x^5=1\rangle$.

Hence, there are two groups of order $45$, namely $C_9\times C_5=C_{45}=\langle x\mid x^{45}=1\rangle$ or $C_3\times C_3\times C_5=\langle x,y,z\mid x^3=y^3=z^5=[x,y]=[x,z]=[y,z]=1\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you very much! And both of these groups are abelian, right?

Comment: Yes, they are both abelian.

Comment: I inderstand. Thank you!